# How to detect collision on a certain collider?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

[image]

I simply what to tell whether the shot is a headshot or not. on the object I'm throwing at, there are two capsule colliders and a sphere collider.
I want to detect if the thrown object hit the sphere collider (headshot)

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple options:

Option **A**: Add 3 empties and add one collider each. Add a script to each of those empties and use the OnCollisionEnter/OnTriggerEnter stuff to detect hits per collider. Or just give each of those colliders a different Tag and compare that using `compareTag`.

Option **B**: You create public/serialized variables and drag the colliders in the slots (inspector). Then, in `OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` compare the passed parameter with your public variables.

example:

```
public SphereCollider head;
public CapsuleCollider body;
public SphereCollider feet;

...

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.collider == head)
    {
        // headshot
    }
}
```

It works the same for triggers (OnTriggerEnter).

If you use a Raycast, here is some important tip: Don't confuse `hit.collider.transform`. with `hit.transform`. (Lets say you wanted to use compareTag on the transforms)

`hit.transform` can be the same as `hit.collider.transform` if the collider is attached to the same transform as the rigidbody (if any). But you can have colliders as children of your rigidbody. Then, `hit.transform` will still return the rigidbodies transform, but `hit.collider.transform` will give you the actual child that has the collider attached, that was hit by the ray.

Comment: for some reason it is not going inside this if(collision.collider == head) block. I don't know why

Comment: hmm, well the "collision" in `OnCollisionEnter` contains the "other" object. (A Collision is always between two colliders) so your player (with head, body, feet) collide with any collider (maybe your bullet object?). Therefore, Option **B** will only work if you put that script on your bullet... Probably not what you wanted. So you'd be stuck with option A.